# Passing parameters to an rspec shared example

Tags: ruby, rspec, parameter-passing

I have a process that returns a result set that I want to test for validity using rspec. The process will return different results based on parameters but there are many examples that are common to all of them so I would like to create a set of common examples that I can run against all of them.

I know that the preferred practice is to use let to build the result. The problem is that each process takes a minute or two to generate a result and I have probably 30 examples. With all of the permutations based on different parameters I am running about 500 examples.If I had to rebuild the result for each example the test would run more than a day.

So instead I am building a result in a before(:all) block and assigning it to an attribute something like this:

```
RSpec.describe 'Test Description' do
  attr_reader :result

  before(:all)
    @result = build_result({some_parameters})
  end

  context 'Some context' do
    it 'Looks lik a result' do 
      expect(result.something).to ...
    end

    it 'Feels lik a result' do 
      expect(result.something).to ...
    end
  end
end
```

Maybe there is a better way than using an attribute. I want to do something like this:

```
RSpec.describe 'Test Description' do
  attr_reader :result

  before(:all)
    @result = build_result({some_parameters})
  end

  context 'Some context' do
    it_behaves_like "A result" result
  end
end
```

Using an attribute in this context fails. Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group all you assertions on result into a single example. This way the let is only evaluated once.

```
RSpec.describe 'Test Description' do
  context 'for params x and y' do
    let(:expected_x) { 'x' }
    let(:expected_y) { 'y' }

    subject { build_result({x: 'x', y: 'y'}) }

    specify :aggregate_failures do
      expect(subject.x).to eq(expected_x)
      expect(subject.y).to eq(expected_y)
    end
  end
end
```

It does go against the "one test, one assertion" guideline, but if the operation is very costly, I think it is a reasonable approach. With [`:aggregate_failures`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures) you will get separate failures for each assertion, so you won't be missing out on that.

Comment: It's not what I was hoping for but it's the best answer so far.

Answer (score 100):

You can pass arguments to shared examples like this:

```
shared_examples_for "A result" do |argument|
 # some tests with argument
end
```

And then pass in `my_argument` like this:

```
it_behaves_like "A result", my_argument
```

Comment: This is the answer you were looking for when you visited this page

Comment: And what if `my_argument` was defined with `let`? It will not work.

Comment: Same question as @gamliela. Can a variable defined with `let` be passed to shared_examples?

Comment: @gamliela, if `my_argument` was defined with `let`, there would be no need to pass it as an argument. You would simply use it directly in `shared_examples`.

Comment: Then that would be a code smell. Especially when the shared examples block is defined in a different file. A shared function should not implicitly rely on global symbols whose semantic meaning might be different on context.

Comment: @gamliela you can pass the factory bot argument as parameter, and in the example group use these in a `let`.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to pass arguments to the shared_example spec file, you should use something like

```
it_behaves_like 'SHARED_EXAMPLE_NAME', { params1: param2, param2: param2 }
```

You can also pass the parameters without hash encapsulation. It depends on how you are going to utilize that param into your shared file.
In my case, I have to call the API with the dynamic params.

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'SHARED_EXAMPLE_NAME' do |params = {}|
```

**FYI:** You cannot pass *Factory* data as param into the shared_example spec file. You have to explicitly call the factory into the shared_example spec file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `let`.

```
let(:result)     { build_result({some_parameters}) }
```

This creates an instance variable that you can use in your test later.

Accord to documentation on [`let`](http://betterspecs.org/#let),

> When you have to assign a variable instead of using a before block to
>   create an instance variable, use let. Using let the variable lazy
>   loads only when it is used the first time in the test and get cached
>   until that specific test is finished.
>
> **BAD**
>
> ```
> describe '#type_id' do
>   before { @resource = FactoryGirl.create :device }
>   before { @type     = Type.find @resource.type_id }
>
>   it 'sets the type_id field' do
>     expect(@resource.type_id).to equal(@type.id)
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> **GOOD**
>
> ```
> describe '#type_id' do
>   let(:resource) { FactoryGirl.create :device }
>   let(:type)     { Type.find resource.type_id }
>
>   it 'sets the type_id field' do
>     expect(resource.type_id).to equal(type.id)
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: The problem with using let is that it is only cached for the duration of the example. If I have 10 "it"s in my test then it is going to calculate the value of the let variable 10 times. In my case it is imperative that I build the result once for the entire context, not for each "it". Otherwise my unit tests will run for more than a day and no one will use them.

Comment: You can use https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/let_it_be to prevent this behaviour and cache `let` between examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments with a block:

```rb
feature 'Index page', js: true do
  context 'Filter' do
    before { visit(statistics_numbers_path) }

    it_behaves_like 'Page with select input', %i[create] do
      given!(:date) { Date.yesterday }
    end
  end
end
```

Shared example `Page with select input` will receive argument `features` contained `[:create]`:

```rb
shared_examples 'Page with select input' do |features|
  context 'Table with results', js: true do
    given!(:existed_number) { 'number_1' }
    given!(:created_number) { 'number_2' }
    given!(:search_regexp) { 'numb' }

    scenario 'You can select existed numbers', skip: !features.include?(:select) do
      number_selector.choose_option(existed_number)

      click_on 'Find'

      expect(page).to have_css('.table tr td', text: existed_number)
    end

    scenario 'You can create tags with new names', skip: !features.include?(:create) do
      number_selector.create_tag(created_number)

      click_on 'Find'

      expect(page).to have_css('.table tr td', text: created_number)
    end

    scenario 'You can search by regular expression', skip: !features.include?(:regexp) do
      number_selector.choose_all_occurrences_of(search_regexp)

      click_on 'Find'

      expect(page).to have_css('.table tr td', text: existed_number)
      expect(page).to have_css('.table tr td', text: created_number)
    end
  end
end
```